# Displaying private PDF in iframe

Tags: php, iframe

I would like to display PDF's from a non-public directory in an iframe. I have found a lot of descriptions about this problem using headers, but always ended up with the PDF filling the full page, meanwhile I would need it to be embedded into the page, e.g. besides a table inside a div.

E.g. this solution displays the PDF, but only the PDF, instead of embedding it into the application.

```
$file='../private/the.pdf';

$filename = 'Custom.pdf'; 

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

@readfile($file);



echo '<iframe src="Custom.pdf" width="500px"></iframe>'`
```

Is it, in any way, possible to access a private PDF from an iframe?

Thank you and sorry if this was already asked before, I read quite a few issues but none of them treated embedding.

Thx,

Comment: Maybe try using <object> tag?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object

Comment: An object would work, and is simple. An iframe can also work, but you need to split the code in your question: The last line goes into your web page, and al the other lines go into a separate PHP file. You then load that file in your iframe by pointing the `src` attribute to it. Exactly the same as you have to do for an object.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, splitting up actually solved it. Thank you :)